# App crash when UITargetedPreview of Context menu changes view on long press - swift

Tags: swift, iphone, contextmenu

I am facing given below crash , when context menu options changes dynamically

'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This UITargetedPreview initializer requires that the view is in a window, but it is not. Either fix that, or use the other initializer that takes a target.

In this scenario the Context menu goes completely blank, see attached screenshot, [image with blank UITargetedPreview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAA65.png)

There shouldn't be crash in such scenario

Comment: Hi Nirali, i got same issue in iOS app with iOS 17 version above only. Is there any solution for this?